# Ajax calls made from Google Spreadsheet Custom Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Has anyone ever tried to write a script inside a Google Spreadsheet to make an ajax call to a website?

I want to make it so that the spreadsheet updates itself from the website. But after just putting this short block of code, I get thrown an error:

> "ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined."

Any idea? Do I have to call a certain library?

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", eventObject[1], true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 16):

Google Apps Script does not support `XMLHttpRequest()` natively, but as you suspected there are services that can accomplish the same thing.

Look at [UrlFetch Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch), [Class Xml](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml/xml) (deprecated) and [Xml Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service).

One of the apps script tutorials ([Accessing Picasa Web Albums through Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/picasa_google_apis)) covers the use of these services, and would be a good place for you to start.